# Cakephp 2 HABTM find with AND conditions

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am trying to use a HABTM association between 2 tables `episodes` and `filters`.  The association table is `episodes_filters`.  I want to find all episodes that match both filter ids 1 and 2.  My understanding is that CakePHP does AND conditions by default, but my efforts have resulted in either returning results matching either episode id 1 or 2, or no results at all.

Here is where I have landed so far with the code:

```
$filterConditions = array();
foreach($filterIds as $filterId ) {
    $filterConditions[] = array('EpisodesFilters.filter_id' => $filterId);
}

$episodeFilters = $this->Episode->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Episode.organization_id' => $this->Auth->user('organization_id'),
        'Episode.status' => $this->request->query['episode_status']
    ),
    'joins' => array(
        array('table' => 'episodes_filters',
            'alias' => 'EpisodesFilters',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                $filterConditions,
                'EpisodesFilters.episode_id = Episode.id'
            )
        )
    ),

));
```

I tried to make each filter id in the JOIN it's own condition instead of doing it as an array like: 'EpisodesFilters.filter_id' => array(1,2), but that results in returning episodes with filters 1 or 2, not both.

Can anyone help me determine how to setup this condition for the HABTM lookup?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($filterIds as $filterId ) {
    $filterConditions['and']['EpisodesFilters.filter_id'][] = $filterId;
}
```

OR without a loop

```
$filterConditions['and']['EpisodesFilters.filter_id'] = $filterIds;
```

Comment: This solutions produces the same result, essentially returning episodes that have a filter id of 1 or 2, not both.

Answer (score 0):

First make your `AND` conditions array, making it a new array for each of the AND conditions separately, from your `$filterIds` var:

```
foreach( $filterIds as $filter_id ) {
    $filterConditions['AND'][] = array('EpidodesFilters.filter_id' => $filter_id);
}
```

And then your conditions item in your find command would be:

```
'conditions' => array(
    'AND' => $filterConditions
)
```